# How to align an Angular grid in CSS?

Tags: css, angular, grid, alignment, center

How is a grid to be aligned in the center of the page with css in an Angular component

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 20px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);    
}
```

I tried margin-left and margin-right in percentage but it doesn't work very elegant.

```
<main>
 <div class="grid-container col-md-9 text-center center">
 <card class="grid-item" [data]="topic"><card>
<ng-container *ngFor="let o of os">
    <card class="grid-item" [data]="o"></card>
</ng-container>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: To confirm, are you trying to use angular material mat-grid, or possibly bootstrap? or your own grid implementation?

Comment: I think I used both of them...

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to just uss css, there's various ways you can do it outlined here:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that in css :

```
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```